Is it possible to reduce number of comparisons from O(N^2) to O(N) in brute-force sorting by using multiplication?
When result of a comparison is assigned to an integer:
r1 = A>B
r2 = B>C

we don't need to compare A against C because
r3 = r1 * r2 = 1

only holds when
A>C

right? Only 2 comparisons and 1 multiplication to find if A>C.
Continuing with an extra element:
r4 = C>D
r3 * r4 = A>D
r1 * r4 = not needed as a,b and c,d are independent
r2 * r4 = B>D
...

So, is there a simple multiply/add way of finding comparison-matrix of all elements without any more comparisons than N? Because with such a matrix, an array of unique elements could be sorted faster than O(N^2) comparisons (but still number of total operations including multiplications should stay same). Can this be modeled as a matrix-multiplication operation (that could be accelerated in tensor cores of CUDA GPU maybe)?
Edit: from derpirscher's comment, it should require more than just adjacent comparisons.
i: index
i > i+1
i > i+2
i > i+4
i > i+8
i > i+N/2 ----> log2 steps ---> nlogn


The lower bound for "sorting with comparisons" is Ω(n * log(n))

@derpirscher then I guess comparing only i and i+1 is not enough. i and i+2, i and i+4, ... i and i+N/2 needed similar to a reduction algorithm.

Correct, you need to iterate through all the elements "N", and compare each element against at least a sample of the sorted elements "log(N)".

And what have you won, if you have N^2 mutliplicationis instead of N^2 comparisons? If you can speed up those mutliplicationis with (I assume) parallelization, you could also find a way to speed up comparisons with parallelization. But parallelization is seldomly considered in theoretical runtime calculations, because those calculations go towards infinity, but you cannot have an infinite degree of parallelization

What you explain at the start is the distinctive property of a transitive relation. A comparison function that defines an order must be transitive. Note that good sorting algorithms already rely on this property.

And finally, this question seems to be off-topic here after all and better suited at https://cs.stackexchange.com  because those are the people who deal with theoretical complexity considerations

@trincot do you mean sorting-networks? I think quick sort does not take this into account. (also quicksort may not be fast enough but its very simple). Or is it about being a stable-sort?

see also http://h.web.umkc.edu/hanyij/html/research/focs02.pdf, it seems for integers you can do better

@huseyintugrulbuyukisik  of course quicksort does take this into account, because it uses a pivot element and partitions the array into "all elements < pivot" and "all elements > pivot". Thus any element being in the lower partition does not need to be compared to any element in the upper partition, but once each partition is sorted you can just merge them "lower parttion pivot upper partition"

@huseyin, I mean any good sorting algorithm. I am not saying they completely avoid making comparisons whose result could have been derived from a pair of previous comparisons, but that they often do, and so rely on the transitive property. The quicksort example is good. Also merge sort will merge two sorted lists with at most O(n) comparisons, and so doing leaves out many comparisons which do not have to be performed because of the transitive property.

@jhole, that article assumes single word integers, which is an import restriction.

@jhole For general comparison based sorting the Ω(n * log(n)) still holds and is prooven. Of course if you limit your domain, to exploit other properties of the data to be sorted you can go lower than that

What makes you think a multiplication is quicker than a comparison?

@MarkRansom because comparisons between floats may require FPU while comparisons by 1/0 value may be run using less bits of word. Something like multiplying 2 values at once by 32 bit integer multiplier (first 16 bit and second 16 bit)

In the best case? Yes.
If you tested the right comparisons, you can definitely sort a list in as few as n-1 comparisons. Because mostly sorted data is common in the real world, some sorting algorithms will try to find runs in the data, and use that to sort more quickly. Timsort is a good example.
But there is no getting around Stirling's Approximation which says that ln(n!) = n ln(n) - n + O(ln(n)). Since a sorting algorithm may rearrange a list in n! ways, it therefore needs at least Ω(n * log(n)) bits (ie comparisons) in most cases. Which means that the average performance of a comparison based algorithm, let alone the worst case performance, cannot be better than that.
Going back to your multiplication idea, what goes wrong? It's simple. While multiplication can give you information about comparisons that you didn't actually do, on average it doesn't.

Comparison sorts require at least n log(n) comparisons, which is a mathematical proof. So yes, the number of comparisons can be reduced from O^2, but not all the way down to linear. @Btilly's answer gives great details about that.
However, you also asked Can this be modeled as a matrix-multiplication operation (that could be accelerated in tensor cores of CUDA GPU maybe)?
Comparison sorts assume a turning machine, like a CPU. But CUDA GPUs are not, and so GPUs can indeed sidestep the limitation, all the way down to O(log n) time (depth), though they often use more comparisons total.  This category of sorting algorithms are called Sorting Networks.  Designing an optimal sorting network for any given n is incredibly difficult, but there's simple algorithms for generating sorting networks that have a depth (time) of O(log(n)^2).  Though fascinating, usually the overhead of coordinating the cores, and the I/O to and from the GPU makes these sorts almost always slower than just doing them on the CPU.
